# copy directory, except for node_modules subdirectory, using tar

Tags: bash, tar

I'm trying to understand how to use `tar` in a Bash script to copy a project directory to another location while excluding the node_modules subdirectory.  There was a potentially useful comment posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders#comment127423754_2193806), which I've rewritten for my use case like so:

```
tar -cf - --exclude="node_modules" "${source}" | tar -xf - -C "${target}"
```

However, I'm reluctant to run this command before understanding a few things about it.  Here are my questions -

1. What is the purpose of the lone hyphen before the `--exclude` and the lone hyphen before the `-C`?
2. Is a .tar file actually created somewhere in the file system?  If so, where and what is it named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `-` argument is defined by many utilities as standard input/output depending on the context, and for GNU `tar` it isn't even needed, as the default file it uses for input/output is stdio. According to that, `tar -cf - --exclude="node_modules" "${source}"` writes a `tar` archive to standard output, which is actually a pipe whose other end is given to the following command `tar -xf - -C "${target}"` as standard input for extraction.
2. In your pipeline standard output is never redirected to a file so no, no `tar` archive is created is actually created.

Comment: Regarding 1...the `-` argument isn't needed for GNU `tar`...does this mean the hyphens could be dropped completely from the statement like this: `tar -cf --exclude="node_modules" "${source}" | tar -xf -C "${target}"`?

Comment: `-f` is a `tar` option with an argument specifying the path of the input/output archive. in both commands the value of this option is `-`. if you want to omit it you must not include the option, that is `tar -cf - --exclude="node_modules" "${source}"` becomes `tar -c --exclude="node_modules" "${source}"`